# Please help me solve my W3C validation API timeout issue

Tags: .net, web-services, multithreading, backgroundworker, w3c

I'm using the W3C validation service to check that the text I type into a TextBox is valid markup.

[image: Valid]

It's almost working.  But, under particular conditions my input results in an error and then endless timeout exceptions.  I have to close an re-open the program to get it working again.

Please glance over my code and help me to solve this issue.

I've got a pretty simple WPF application with a TextBox and a StatusBar.  The StatusBar updates as I type to let me know if my typed markup is or is not valid.  So that I'm not hammering the service, validations occur only after one second or longer has elapsed with no keystrokes.

[Invalid http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3788/invalidr.gif](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3788/invalidr.gif)

It StatusBar may show: "Validating...", "Valid", "Invalid", or--if there's been one--an exception's message.

[Validating http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/5842/validating.gif](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/5842/validating.gif)

The following validates successfully:

### XHTML Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>This is a test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I break my paragraph like `<p>This is a test</` then I get this exception while trying to process the response XML:

> Name cannot begin with the '"'
>   character, hexadecimal value 0x22.
>   Line 86, position 40.

[XML Exception http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3066/namecannotbegin.gif](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/3066/namecannotbegin.gif)

If validation fails like that twice in a row, then it seems I can't just fix my paragraph tags and continue on like normal.  For some reason each subsequent validation fails with this exception:

> The operation has timed out

[Timed Out http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7600/timedout.gif](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7600/timedout.gif)

This is very strange.

I'm sorry to post my whole project, but I don't know where my problem is coming from.  It might be my threading, web service communication, exception handling... I just can't seem to find it.  Am I closing my StreamWriter, HttpWebRequest, and ResponseStreams correctly?

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="W3C Validation"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        Name="Window1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 FontFamily="Consolas"
                 TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockResult" />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Visual Basic

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports <xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
Imports <xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/markup-validator">

Class Window1

    Private WithEvents Worker As BackgroundWorker
    Private _WorkerArgument As String

    Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        InitializeWorker()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeWorker()
        Worker = New BackgroundWorker
        Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler Worker.DoWork, AddressOf Worker_DoWork
        AddHandler Worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf Worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)
        TryToWork(DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text)
    End Sub

    Sub TryToWork(ByVal Argument As String)

        If _WorkerArgument IsNot Nothing Then
            _WorkerArgument = Argument
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not Worker.IsBusy Then
            TextBlockResult.Text = "Validating..."
            Worker.RunWorkerAsync(Argument)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        _WorkerArgument = Argument
        Worker.CancelAsync()
        Dim RetryTimer As New Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
        AddHandler RetryTimer.Tick, AddressOf RetryTicker
        RetryTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(1) '1 tick'
        RetryTimer.Start()

    End Sub

    Sub RetryTicker(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not Worker.IsBusy Then
            DirectCast(sender, Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer).Stop()
            TextBlockResult.Text = "Validating..."
            Worker.RunWorkerAsync(_WorkerArgument)
            _WorkerArgument = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        'wait for one second'
        Dim StartTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
        While Now.Subtract(StartTime) < New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
            If DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100)) 'tenth of a second'
        End While
        'then validate'
        e.Result = Validate(DirectCast(e.Argument, String))
    End Sub

    Private Function Validate(ByVal Text As String) As String
        Try
            Dim Url As String = "http://validator.w3.org/check"
            Dim Post As String = "&fragment=" + Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Text) + "&output=soap12"
            Dim ResponseDocument As XDocument = XDocument.Load(New Xml.XmlTextReader(Communicate(Url, Post)))
            If ResponseDocument.Root.<env:Body>.<m:markupvalidationresponse>.<m:validity>.Value = "true" Then
                Return "Valid"
            Else
                Return "Invalid"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function Communicate(ByVal Url As String, ByVal Post As String) As System.IO.Stream
        Dim Writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
        Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url)
        Request.Method = "POST"
        Request.ContentLength = Post.Length
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Request.Timeout = 2000 '2 seconds'
        Try
            Writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream())
            Writer.Write(Post)
        Catch
        Finally
            If Not Writer Is Nothing Then
                Writer.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return Request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()
    End Function

    Private Sub Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        If Not e.Cancelled Then
            TextBlockResult.Text = DirectCast(e.Result, String)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't worry about posting so much code.  We like code.  Easier to find bugs in code than guess from vauge descriptions.

Comment: Are you using a locally installed copy of the service (http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) or the one hosted at w3.org?

Comment: I'm using the service hosted at w3.org.

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance, I would recomend not trying to validate every time the text is changed.  That can, and does, get a bit overwhelming.  I fear that is what is going on here.  Good job on making it Async as that will keep it from blocking but I also suspect it is hiding your issue.

Try having the TextChanged event set a flag to execute the validator and then just have the DoWork method run in a tight(ish) loop checking that flag.  That will allow it time to complete and not get confused.  It might take a second or two to get the correct data but shouldn't lock up.

Good luck.

Comment: Additionally you could get blocked if you do this.  It says in their docs http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html that excessive use will get blocked.

Comment: I've built in a 1-second-or-greater delay between each validation per their suggestion.